# Embedding HTML into webbrowser - script error

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control, embed

I'm trying to embed some HTML code into a webbrowser.

The code I'm using to do this is:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")
WebBrowser1.Document.Write(String.Empty)
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = My.Resources.HTML
```

'HTML' in my resources contains an HTML file with [this](https://puu.sh/yIzsv/fae7784a64.png)

This is the [script error](https://puu.sh/yIzic/109e03abe3.png) that shows up. For some reason it inserts "about://" before the URL and doesn't show anything in the webbrowser. I've tried looking this issue up but the only solutions I've found are to suppress script errors which does not solve my problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post all relevant code and messages as text, don't just link to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using a relative path in the `<script>` tag (you forgot http://), the browser is attempting to find the script in the same location as the current, which is `about:blank`, so it will try to find the script in `about:`. Just add `http://` to the script URL and you'll be fine.